# what is difference in outlook macro used, between personal and shared/public/exchange inbox?

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server

I have a macro which I believe is used for a personal inbox in outlook.

Where and what must be changed in the code so that, the macro can be implemented for public/shared /exchange inbox?

The code fragment used for personal inbox

```
Dim objSourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder      
Set objSourceFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a public Inbox (if you mean Public Folders store).

There is no difference between a PST and Exchange based primary Inbox folder - both are retrieved using Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).

Delegate Exchange Inbox can be retrieved using Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(Recipient, olFolderInbox).

Comment: Thanks Dimitry. I dont have much knowledge on macros. So I got a follow up query. I want to use this macro for a inbox that is shared by 8 persons at my work. We use a common email ID (helpdesk@xx.com) where emails come in and I basically want to apply a macro to that shared inbox so that aged emails with same subject lines are deleted/moved with just keeping the most recent one in the inbox. So what value the Recipient parameter uses here? If I have to set a value for it , how do I do it?

Comment: Also should this macro run on the outlook of all the 8 persons or only one ? Thanks again

Comment: yes. Call Namespace.CreateRecipient("helpdesk@xx.com"), then pass the returned Recipient object to GetSharedDefaultFolder.

Comment: Thanks Dimitry..this should really help.